# Regex expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex keeps returning false and I cannot see why?
I have an onkeydown event that triggers this, I've tried 'w' key and it doesn't work.

```
var keyGLOB = '';

function editProductSearch (event) {
    console.log(keyGLOB);
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(event.keyCode == 8) {
        keyGLOB = keyGLOB.substring(0, keyGLOB.length -1);
        return false;
    }
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if(regex.test(key)) {
        if(regex.test(keyGLOB)) {
            keyGLOB += key;
            searchDb(keyGLOB.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            alert('letters and numbers only!');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert('letters and numbers only!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><input id='product-edit-search' onkeydown='editProductSearch(event)'></p>
```

Comment: What are you testing it against?

Comment: What is `key`?  What is `keyGLOB`?

Comment: Because `key` and/or `keyGLOB` contains something other than letters and numbers? Without your input, how is anybody supposed to guess what's happening?

Comment: Your code works. My guess is that your input contains non alpha/numeric (perhaps spaces) or you do not have that code within a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    if(regex.test(keyGLOB)) {
        keyGLOB += key;
```

In the **if clause**, keyGLOB is still an empty string based on how it was defined earlier in your program, which I believe would return false based on your regex.

Comment: Thats it! thanks, what can i add to the regex to allow it to accept an empty string?

Comment: Yeah. The `alert` being triggered is actually the one within the `else` clause of the `if(regex.test(keyGLOB)) {`, not the outer one. It seems the OP is mistaking one for another.

Comment: Just make the text optional: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/` (`*` instead of `+`).